# How to authenticate and requestWithGraphPath for facebook at the same time in iOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I am integrating my iOS app with facebook. I want to authenticate and send requestWithGraphPath at the same time. How can i do that? Write now i am using following code:

```
 if (!facebook.isSessionValid) {
            NSLog(@"in else login button tapped");
            NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"user_likes", 
                                    @"publish_stream",
                                    @"user_about_me",
                                    @"email",
                                    nil];
            [facebook authorize:permissions];
            [permissions release];

            [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; 
        }
```

but after requestWithGraphPath is called. My app keep waiting. but next time when i come again and press button then it works fine. Can authenticate and requestWithGraphPath  work at the same time when facebook.isSessionValid is false? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have authorized, if you've setup the delegate properly. And the user comes back to your app, the method:

```
 -(void)fbDidLogin {

 }
```

Should trigger, and there you can request the graphPath.